# Refresher on Java classes in separate files

Tags: java, class

I need a refresher on moving classes from one file into two files.  My sample code is in one file called "**external_class_file_main**".  The program runs fine and the code is shown below:

```
Public class external_class_file_main {

    public static int get_a_random_number (int min, int max) {
        int n;
        n = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;
        return (n);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r;
        System.out.println("Program starting...");

        r = get_a_random_number (1, 5);
        System.out.println("random number = " + r);

        System.out.println("Program ending...");

    }

}
```

I move the **get_a_random_number** class to a separate file called "**external_class_file**".  When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method get_a_random_number(int, int) is undefined for the type
external_class_file_main
at external_class_file_main.main(external_class_file_main.java:20)
```

The "**external_class_file_main**" now contains:

```
public class external_class_file_main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r;
        System.out.println("Program starting...");

        r = get_a_random_number (1, 5);
        System.out.println("random number = " + r);

        System.out.println("Program ending...");

    }

}
```

The "**external_class_file**" now contains:

```
public class external_class_file {

    public static int get_a_random_number (int min, int max) {
        int n;
        n = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;
        return (n);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to refer t `get_a_random_number` via the class `external_class_file`. E.g.:

```
int r;
System.out.println("Program starting...");
r = external_class_file.get_a_random_number (1, 5);
```

You should definitely stick to Java naming conventions though.

Answer (score 1):

You no longer have access to the get_a_random_number method from the external_class_file_main class. As the method you need is static you can just refer directly to it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int r;
    System.out.println("Program starting...");

    r = external_class_file.get_a_random_number (1, 5);
    System.out.println("random number = " + r);

    System.out.println("Program ending...");

}
```

PS you will find it a lot easier to code and for people reading your questions if you use proper Java naming conventions for your methods and classes e.g. no underscores and start classes with a capital letter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29

Comment: The method is static, the OP doesn't need to create an instance of `external_class_file` to access the method ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution:

```
public class external_class_file_main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r;
        System.out.println("Program starting...");

        r = external_class_file.get_a_random_number (1, 5);
        System.out.println("random number = " + r);

        System.out.println("Program ending...");

    }

}
```

But, please, take a look into Java naming conventions.